# Apache and backslashes in mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, backslash, friendly-url

I want to process all incoming requests through a single script (`index.php` in web-root).

So, the following is what currently happens: `http://localhost/foo/bar/baz`

Is routed by Apache (through `.htaccess`) to: `http://localhost/index.php?url=foo/bar/baz`

---

This works well, however, in Firefox I am able to do this: `http://localhost/foo\` -> notice the *backslash*.

And Apache, instead of doing: `/index.php?url=foo\`

Emits a generic error page saying:

> **Object not found!** The requested URL
>   was not found on this server. If you
>   entered the URL manually please check
>   your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error,
>   please contact the webmaster.
>
> **Error 404** localhost Apache/2.2.14
>   (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14
>   OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color
>   PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1
>   mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

Directly going to: `http://localhost/index.php?url=foo\` works without issues, however.

---

All the sites that I've seen on the internet seem to be able to handle backslashes gracefully (e.g., `http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php\\\\\`).

I consider this behavior a bug and I want to force Apache to forward backslashes correctly.
Here's my `.htaccess` file in its entirety:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

How can I make this work properly?

---

Edit: I just tried this on my webhost and this is handled properly by them. Makes me think it's some setting in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: Possible Bug: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42499, also try adding to your htaccess `AllowEncodedSlashes On`

Comment: @RobertPitt: thanks, I didn't know about `AllowEncodedSlashes`. When adding it to my `.htaccess` file, the server ISEs (HTTP 500), though. This happens on my local development box (Windows) as well as my webhost (Linux). Looking at the Apache documentation for it, it seems like its context is listed as: `server config, virtual host`, so no support for `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably need AcceptPathInfo off to not get those tolerated as forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this issue on WampServer on Windows. [This page](http://www.jampmark.com/web-scripting/5-solutions-to-url-encoded-slashes-problem-in-apache.html) had the solution - the `AllowEncodedSlashes` option that RobertPitt mentions above is the correct one, but it must go in the `http.conf` file, inside a VirtualHost block, eg:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
</VirtualHost>
```

It doesn't work in a `.htaccess` file.